C++ - How to prevent function reordering in MSVC
I have created simple function and tried to measure execution time of it.
Unfortunately because of function reordering measured time is always 0.
My sample code:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

__declspec(noinline) double test(int num_intervals) {
    double dx = 1.0 / num_intervals;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_intervals; ++i) {
        double x = (i + 0.5) * dx;
        double h = std::sqrt(1 - x * x);
        sum += h * dx;
    }
    double pi = 4 * sum;
    return pi;
}

int main() {
    int num_intervals = 1000000000;
    double serial_time = 0.0;
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double pi = test(num_intervals);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    serial_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    std::cout << "serial pi == " << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << "serial_time == " << serial_time << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << t0.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t1.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output:
serial pi == 3.14159
serial_time == 0 ms
167375943888100
167375943888100

From generated assembly I see that both calls to compute t1 and t0 are reordered and executed before function test.
Is such optimization valid (according to C++ standard) ? Is there any way to disable such reordering (but still having all possible optimizations enabled?)
I've tries to apply _ReadWriteBarrier and  std::atomic_thread_fence but without any success.
Godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/j916GG9jK
Computation of t0 is in line: 1486, and t1 in line: 1488.
Computation of pi is in line: 1490 (after t1 and t0)
gcc/clang reports the execution time properly.
It makes quite difficult time measurement as without looking into assembly I never know if part of my computations wasn't reordered before/after time measurement block.

you should use a tool for this like google benchmark.  You can try that live online at quick-bench

@NathanOliver I love google benchmark and similar ones, but If I wan't to measure some execution time on production (as e.g. input parameter, hardware configuration etc. are not known in advance) then std clock seems to be right choice. But looking for robust way of doing it.

adding volatile in front of double pi made it work, but I am not sure if it is guaranteed.

"Is such optimization valid (according to C++ standard) ?" Timing is not an "observable behavior".


Is such optimization valid (according to C++ standard) ?

Sure. The functions have no observable side effects on any data, so they can be executed whenever, up to the point where their result becomes necessary.
In your case, these functions can be evaluated completely at compile time. So they might not have to be executed at run time at all.

serial_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();


Note that a millisecond is a very long time for a computer, and duration_cast will only truncate, not round properly. Anything up to 999.9… µs is 0 ms after casting. (Not a big problem in your case, probably, you're doing very many iterations, after all. But your loop only takes ~4s, so you're in the "observable, but statistically probably not already relevant" region of quantizing time incorrectly.)
"In production", the situation is much less problematic. Things that time would be found by instrumentation and stack pointer sampling, not by using std::chrono, because that comes at a potentially high cost. A lot of time you don't care about functions that just compute natural constants, but about functions that allocate memory, or that talk to network, or that exchange data with a GPU… and these are all functions with side effects, which means they can't be executed at arbitrary points.

In some cases std::chrono is still valid case even in production. e.g. if we want present to user the execution time. For analyzing purpose of course tools like VTune/perf are much better. The sample code comes from TBB book and is just a simple demo to show the problem. But the problem itslef looked very interesting to me as the reporting time was always 0 and I wanted to understand the root cause and find the right approach.

According to the standard if function Test would have side effect. Would it be guaranteed by standard that std::chrono:: can't be reordered before Test ? For me it looks like the observabke behavior is still the same and could be reordered because std::chrono has no side effects.

if you present a time to a user, then you react to an external stimulus and your delivery of the result is a side effect, so the reordering problem doesn't arise.

std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), unlike your test, has side effects (what exactly is the observable side effect of test? ...::now() interacts with an externality, the clock).

huh. On closer testing, MSVC seems to think that steady_clock::now() has no side effects. That's … a bug? Not sure.

Thanks, now it makes perfect sense. I misunerstood @Jarod42 comment above and tought that '...::now' has no side effect.
